# Is there something between middleware and view in Django so that I can plug my code into?

Tags: django, url-routing, django-views, django-middleware

Is there something between `middleware` and view so that I can plug my code or do I have to subclass something from `Django` to provide this functionality?

Let me first explain why I need this, maybe there is a better solution that you can suggest. I want to restrict some of my url's based on some configuration. And,
 - I want this configuration to be part of url configuration
 - According to the config provided, I want to redirect, etc to some other view.

What I mean by 'part of url configuration' is something like the following.

```
url(r'^admin/blah/blah$', do_something, name='admin-blah-blah', {'security_level': 'very_secure', 'auth_method' : 'oauth', 'auth_url', 'http://www.foo.com'})
```

It seems like it is something that should be done by middlewares, but I don't want to do it with middlewares for 2 reasons.
 - I don't want to maintain a separate config.
 - I don't want to do regex matching for url patterns one more time, url resolver is already doing that

So if I can just find a way to plug some functionality just before view and can reach the configuration provided, it solves my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you could do this with a decorator on your views:

```
@restrict_url(security_level='very_secure', auth_method='oauth', 
              auth_url= 'http://www.foo.com')
def my_view(request):
    ... etc ...
```

You can get some ideas of how to write the `restrict_url` decorator by looking at the ones provided in `django.contrib.auth.decorators`.

Comment: That is elegant, I should read the django docs first :) thanks for pointing out.